# Identifying if symbols is/are present in the Product Name

Tags: c#, .net

I have this list of products that I need to Identify that has the pattern symbols. So far below is the code that I used to identify them. Unfortunately when I debug the program, it doesn't recognized the pattern.

```
            string[] patterns = new string[] { "." ,",", ";", "'", "`", ":", "/", "\\", "*", "|" ,"(", ")","[", "]", "{", "}", "<",  ">" };

            List<Product> products = new List<Product>
            {
                new Product { ID = 1, Name = "Jenny's Product", Price = 10 },
                new Product { ID = 2, Name = "Brunus C.O.", Price = 10 },
                new Product { ID = 3, Name = "GreenCross", Price = 10 },

            };
            foreach (var item in products)
            {
               if (patterns.Contains(item.Name))
               {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
               }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
patterns.Contains(item.Name)
```

Why would it recognize the patterns, you are asking if the item name is contained in the patterns. It's not. You want to ask if any pattern is contained in the item's name:

```
patterns.Any(item.Name.Contains)
```